# SEVEN-COUNTERS GAME

Tags: visual, strategy

<sub>This simple puzzle is from the 1908 book “A Scrap-Book of Elementary Mathematics” by William F. White.</sub>

---

Required to place seven counters on seven of the eight spots in conformity to the following rule: To place a counter, one must set out from a spot that is unoccupied and move along a straight line to the spot where the counter is to be placed.

[image: 8 empty spots with lines joining some spots]

---

*Clarification (from GentlePurpleRain):*

*For each counter, you must pick an empty spot, then move along a line to another empty spot where you place the counter.*

---

**To allow new users to solve this puzzle and earn reputation points, I encourage all users whose reputation is 200 or more to not post an answer until 48 hours after this question is posted. Thank you!**

---

Comment: The problem description is not well-worded.  I first interpreted it to mean that you pick a spot that is unoccupied (any of them), and move along the lines, placing counters.  That makes it an extremely trivial problem.
But I think the intention is that for *each counter*, you must pick an empty spot, then move along a line to another empty spot where you place the counter.  That makes the problem slightly less trivial (although a solution becomes apparent to me fairly quickly).

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Thanks for your comment.  I have added a clarification to the wording of the puzzle.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain to be honest perhaps your two interpretations are equivalent because the solutions are [redacted to avoid spoilers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my representation, unoccupied points are represented by letters and occupied points are represented by counters (numbers):

```
  A  B
H      C
G      D
  F  E
```

Step 1:

> Start with any unoccupied point: say A. A links to both D and F. Set out
>  from a spot that is unoccupied (**A**) and move along a straight line to the
>  spot where the counter is to be placed (**F**):
>
> ```
>    A  B
>  H      C
>  G      D
>    1  E
> ```

Step 2:

> F is linked both from A and C. Since you've already came from A, the
>  strategy is to set the next counter in C. Set out from a spot that is
>  unoccupied (**H**) and move along a straight line to the spot where the
>  counter is to be placed (**C**):
>
> ```
>    A  B
>  H      2
>  G      D
>    1  E
> ```

Step 3:

> C is linked both by F and H. Since F is already occupied by 1, the strategy
>  is to set the next counter in H. Set out from a spot that is unoccupied
>  (**E**) and move along a straight line to the spot where the counter is to
>  be placed (**H**):
>
> ```
>    A  B
>  3      2
>  G      D
>    1  E
> ```

Step 4:

> H is linked both by C and E. Since C is already occupied by 2, the strategy
>  is to set the next counter in E. Set out from a spot that is unoccupied
>  (**B**) and move along a straight line to the spot where the counter is to
>  be placed (**E**):
>
> ```
>    A  B
>  3      2
>  G      D
>    1  4
> ```

Therefore,

> following this pattern, you'll get as final result:
>
> ```
>    A  5
>  3      2
>  6      7
>    1  4
> ```